# fsck.ext4 does not fix a few corrupt files?

Tags: fsck

I ran this `fsck.ext4 -vf /dev/sdb2`, and the files were still corrupt (garbage data);
`/dev/sdb2` is on a SSD;
I had to use `-f` because `/dev/sdb2` was clean!

- My only hope is a backup?
- Or is there another command that could restore the files in some way?
- Or may be some configuration that makes the writes more sure/safe, even if the filesystem gets slower? may be something that could be enabled on the fly without re-mounting?

PS.: I just had written the files and the blackout happened; not all files got corrupt, just a few; This question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87555/are-short-lived-files-flushed-to-disk, has some info on how data is written/flushed to the disk, but is not quite what I am looking for I guess..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fsck` can only get the filesystem meta data back into a sane state so that it won't confuse the kernel.  If you had file data that was not written at the time of a crash, then it is gone.

Comment: that is the point, the file was written; the crash happened after that, about 5min; so my only guess is the data wasnt "actually written" to the SSD for some reason? may be was still on SSD cache or even memory? I dont know how that works..

Comment: @AquariusPower, the default settings flush data to disk within several seconds after the application has written it.  Things like `pm-powersave` and the laptop-mode-tools package alter the default settings so that it can take up to 10 minutes ( more more if you change it ) to flush, to avoid waking up a sleeping disk drive.

Comment: mmm mine is an SSD, if that is setup to anything greater that 0.1s is a missconfiguration IMO... I will try to find a way to check that configuration and if needed change it, any idea what command to check that?

Comment: @AquariusPower, to set it permanently, you edit /etc/fstab.

Comment: all of them are set to 5s! I saw with: `find /proc/fs/ -name options |sort |while read strFile; do grep -H commit $strFile;done` I am not sure yet if it is advisable change it to 1s on ssd and others.. I think what I really need is a no-break.. ok thx!